# Put anonymous function into named function?

Tags: javascript

i'm using this script:

```
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName("listener"),
function(elem)
{

  elem.addEventListener("click", function()

  {

    // action 

  });

})
```

After adding new content dynamically it ignores new elements of course.

So is it possible to put this code inside another function? Which is called with window.onload() to work with existing elements **AND** on demand when new elements have been added?

Comment: Use event delegation instead.

Comment: You can set named functions as event listeners you would just name the function then add the event listener like elem.addEventListener("click", handler); or elem.onclick=handler; where handler is a named function

Comment: It is obviously possible to put any JavaScript code in a function. You may want to try that and than update question with information of what did not work... (Side note: you may consider using JQuery as it is much easier to express such code with `JQuery.on` and than study how it is implemented)